# How can I force the Excel SMALL function to return all results satisfying an IF criterion?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in which I would like to return the text of all cells in MyTable field "Result" in which the corresponding text in MyTable field "Query" matches a string in $C$1, as a list. I want to do this using formulas. I know that my formula will need to have the following form:

`=INDEX(MyTable[Result],SMALL(IF(MyTable[Query]=C1,ROW(MyTable[Result]),""),___))`

The issue is that I'm not sure what should go in the ___. I want my formula to return strings from all relevant cells, not just a fixed number of cells, because I don't know now many cells match the criteria. As far as I understand, `SMALL` throws an error if the number provided as the last argument exceeds the number of non-empty strings returned by the `IF` function. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `k` argument can be an array.  And the upper bounds can probably be calculated using `COUNTIF` in your case.

Arrays can be constructed in a variety of ways.

One way (**not** the most efficient) would be something like:

```
=row(indirect("1:" & countif(MyTable[Query],C1)))
```

You can also use the `INDEX` function to construct the array, and, if speed is an issue, this would be better as it is a non-volatile function.